# how to make back button work after adding category.DEFAULT

Tags: android, android-intent, homescreen

I have an app and I wanted it to replace it with the default homescreen, so that whenever the phone starts on boot-up or when the home button is pressed. For this I  used an intent filter.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

But, the back button doesn't work in this case and I'm not able to go back to my original homescreen.
Is there any way, I can make app appear when phone boot-up or home button is pressed and when the back button is pressed, the default homescreen appears.

Comment: Why would you want that sort of functionality?

Answer (score 1):

```
Try overriden function OnBackPressed()

 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

          moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event){ 
     int action = event.getAction();
     int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
         switch (keyCode) {
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:                            
                if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP)
                //DO something

                    return true;


           default:
             return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
                }
     }
```